# What's behind that it's not possible to handle widgets on different pages without plugins and hacks? (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

Basic Question: Is there a way to handle the visibility of widgets on pages WITHOUT plugins and custom coding? If not, why not? Isn't this the main issue every user goes about while developing a new website? (e.g show recent events only on event page in the left sidebar)

I know there are several plugins and actually I'm working with Woo Sidebars and Widget Logic. And it works well but...

Why I need a plugin for this behavior, 99% of websites need to handle different (side) content. Do only I think this should be a default feature?

I'm asking because I usually work with (enterprise) cms where I can manage widgets directly on every page and didn't have to manage widgets on a global admin page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm... as a CMS, not customized, Wordpress will seem lacking when compared with commercial alternatives. Without customizations in the theme or via plug-ins, it's just a simple blogging platform.

It's really sexy when used as a developer's platform. It's simplicity up front is what allows us developers to turn it into anything we need it to be.

If a vote were held, I'd vote not to have independent sidebars on every page. The majority of my clients have no need for different sidebar content on every page. I'd end up having to configure duplicate sidebars on hundreds of pages. It's much easier to create  a new page template for the rare page that does need it's own sidebar content, or create a simple widget that shows sibling pages in the sidebar. Really, with Wordpress there are a few different ways to address this problem: custom page template, custom widgets, custom fields, etc.

Comment: now half year later, and several websites done. i'd agree with you :)